# How to add scores from external file into a dictionary and rank them from 1 to 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary

I'm doing my python dice roll game for school, and have ran into trouble with files and dictionaries. I have a file with 10 scores and 10 names, next to each other respectively, and can get it to bring in the 10 existing ones, and sort them, but can't manage to get new scores and names in.

Tried updating the dictionary with `dict.update()` but it throws a
`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`:

```py
highScores = {}

with open("highscores.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        highScores[int(key)] = val

for k, v in sorted(highScores.items()):
    print(k,v)
score = input("S: ")
user = input("N: ")
winner = {score:user}
highScores.update(winner)

for k, v in sorted(highScores.items()):
    print(k,v)
```

Comment: What is in `highscores.txt`?  Not a description; the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I suppose `highscores.txt` looks something like

```
100 user1
90 user2
95 user3
...
```

Since `input(__prompt: Any) -> str` returns type `str`, you have to change your `winner` dict to contain a k,v-pair with a key of type `int` (just like you did in `highScores[int(key)] = val`):

```py
winner = {int(score) : user}
```

The error is telling you that `str` and `int` can't be compared with the `>` operator. Take a look at the implementation of the comparison operator in `builtins.pyi`:

```py
class int:
    def __gt__(self, x: int) -> bool: ...
```